# IEnumerable Extension Methods on an Enum

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, enums

I have an enum(below) that I want to be able to use a LINQ extension method on.

```
enum Suit{
    Hearts = 0,
    Diamonds = 1,
    Clubs = 2,
    Spades = 3
}
```

Enum.GetValues(...) is of return type System.Array, but I can't seem to get access to a ToList() extension or anything else of that sort.

I'm just looking to write something like...

```
foreach(Suit s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)).Select(x=>x).Where(x=> x != param)){}
```

Is there something I'm missing, or can someone explain to me why this isn't possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`Enum.GetValues` returns a [`System.Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) and `System.Array` only implements `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` so you will need to use the [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method to convert the `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<Suit>` like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit))
            .OfType<Suit>()
            .Where(x => x != param);
```

**Edit:** I removed the call to `IEnumerable.Select` as it was a superfluous projection without any meaningful translation.  You can freely filter the `IEnumerable<Suit>` that is returned from `OfType<T>`.

Comment: I tend to see `OfType` more appropriate for when you're looking to filter a list, and `Cast` for casting.  Is there a reason to use `Int32` rather than `Suit`?

Comment: For any `IEnumerable` that contains homogeneous types, `OfType<T>` and `Cast<T>` will perform and behave virtually identically.  As for using `Int32` rather than `Suit` I am not really sure why I did that - my answer has been corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Array implements IEnumerable so you'll need to use `Cast<Suit>` or `OfType<Suit>` to get the `IEnumerble<T>` extensions like ToList();