# How can I create an IEnumerable from an enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IEnumerable Extension Methods on an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752194/ienumerable-extension-methods-on-an-enum)
>   [How can I use Generics to create a way of making an IEnumerable from an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447799/how-can-i-use-generics-to-create-a-way-of-making-an-ienumerable-from-an-enum)

Given enums like this:

```
public enum City
{
    London    = 1,
    Liverpool  = 20,
    Leeds       = 25
}

public enum House
{
    OneFloor    = 1,
    TwoFloors = 2
}
```

How can I convert these into an IEnumerable lists with two fields named "data" and "value". Would it be possible to have a generic method or way of doing this? Please not that the values are not always sequential.

Comment: Do you want an IEnumerable of Tuple, a IDictionary or what?

Comment: I think it would need to be an IDictionary as I need field names. Would appreciate any advice you can give me with this.

Comment: Check driis' answer for IEnumerable of Anonymous Types (they may as well be Tuples), check mine for a bit old school (no Linq) IDictionary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
City[] values = (City[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(City));
var valuesWithNames = from value in values
                      select new { value = (int)value, name = value.ToString() };
```

Comment: Thanks I did see the GetValues but I am not sure how to take these and put them in a collection that has field names?

Comment: Please see updated answer, where I select the integer values and their names into an `IEnumerable` using an anonymous type. From there, put them in the data structure you need.

Comment: I will try this now. I think it's what I need.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
//Tested on LINQPad
void Main()
{
    var test = GetDictionary<City>();
    Console.WriteLine(test["London"]);
}

public static IDictionary<string, int> GetDictionary<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (type.IsEnum)
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(type);
        var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            result.Add(value.ToString(), (int)value);
        }
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

public enum City
{
    London = 1,
    Liverpool = 20,
    Leeds = 25
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var cities Enum.GetValues(typeof(City)).OfType<City>()
               .Select(x =>
                    new
                    {
                         Value =  (int)x,
                         Text = x.ToString()
                    });
```

**EDIT**

with cast instead of OfType

```
var cities = ((IEnumerable<City>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(City)))
                                     .Select(x => 
                                         new 
                                         {
                                             Value =  (int)x,
                                             Text = x.ToString()
                                         });
```

Comment: Maybe `Cast` instead of `OfType`?