# How can I use Generics to create a way of making an IEnumerable from an enum?

Tags: c#

Given an enum like this:

```
public enum City {
    London    = 1,
    Liverpool  = 20,
    Leeds       = 25
}

public enum House {
    OneFloor    = 1,
    TwoFloors = 2
}
```

I am using the following code to give me an IEnumerable:

```
City[] values = (City[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(City)); 
var valuesWithNames = from value in values                       
   select new { value = (int)value, name = value.ToString() };
```

The code works very good however I have to do this for quite a lot of enums. Is there a way I could create a generic way of doing this?

Comment: The problem is that C# doesn't allow `enum` constraints on generic types. You can use Jon Skeet's [unconstrained melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/).

Comment: If you need the `IEnumerable` only at runtime you can use reflection. Otherwise you may consider using [templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) AND reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function might help you:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetValues<T>() where T : struct
{
        var t = typeof(T);
        if(!t.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum type");

        return Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<T>().Select (x => 
               new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
                   (int)Enum.ToObject(t, x), 
                    x.ToString()));
}
```

Usage:

```
var values = GetValues<City>();
```

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` is defined as *"The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state."*    That seems like a really misleading exception to throw.

Comment: A `TypeArgumentException` like the one defined in *UnconstrainedMelody* would be ideal. The closest fitting predefined exception is probably `ArgumentException` though *("The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.")*

Answer (score 3):

Use Jon Skeet's [unconstrained melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/).

```
using UnconstrainedMelody;
```

---

You can put your enum values into a `Dictionary<int, string>` and then enumerate over them:

```
var valuesAsDictionary = Enums.GetValues<City>()
                              .ToDictionary(key => (int)key, value => value.ToString());
```

---

But you probably don't even need to do that. Why not just enumerate over the values directly:

```
foreach (var value in Enums.GetValues<City>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", (int)value, value);
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting to `int` and not `T`? Enums do not have to be ints, and there's no reason you can't return a `Dictionary<T, string>` instead.

Comment: @Lee In the question she explicitly wants int and string.

Comment: @Lee but then again, why create a dictionary at all when all the information you need exists within the enum value itself? This is the point I tried to express in the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
    IEnumerable<object> GetValues<T>()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof (T))
                   .Cast<T>()
                   .Select(value => new {     
                                             value = Convert.ToInt32(value),
                                             name = value.ToString()
                                         });

    }
```

So you can use:

```
var result = GetValues<City>();
```

If you would like to make constraint generic `T` as `enum`, because `enum` *cannot be used as generic contraint directly*, but [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inherits from interface `IConvertible`, believe this way is okay:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetValues<T>() where T: struct, IConvertible
{}
```

To replace `IEnumerable<object>` by `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<int, string> GetValues<T>() where T :  struct, IConvertible
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof (T)).Cast<T>()
               .ToDictionary(value => Convert.ToInt32(value),
                             value => value.ToString());
}
```

**Edit**: As Magnus's comment, if you need to make sure the order of items, Dictionary is not the option. Define your own strong type would be better.

Comment: I see two problems with returning a Dictionary: First it is unordered. Second it seems unnecessary to return a dictionary if it is not going to be used for lookup.

Comment: @Magnus: True with unordered, reason why I use is Dictionary is stronger type than IEmmerable<object>.