# How can I create an IEnumerable from an enum using its System.Type

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I am trying to unserialize enum types.

I need a method with this prototype:

```
private static object CSVConvertParam(string value, System.Type t);
```

So I can use it this way:

```
enum MyEnum { val1=0, val2=1, val3=2 ...}
...
System.Type enumType = typeof(MyEnum);
...
var unserializedVal = CSVConvertParam("val3", enumType );
```

I have read this nearly similar question:
[How can I create an IEnumerable from an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447473/how-can-i-create-an-ienumerable-from-an-enum)

But in my case, the type is unknown at compile time.

It must be very close of this:

```
private static object CSVConvertParam(string value, System.Type t)
{
 int enumIndex = ( (IEnumerable<????>) t.GetEnumValues()).ToList().IndexOf( value);
return  (Enum)Enum.ToObject(t, enumIndex);

}
```

except that I would need to know the concrete type that t represents to have the  (IEnumerable) cast to work.

Is there a way to solve this?

EDIT:
I tried to make a generic version that would solve this issue:

```
 private static object CSVConvertParam<T>(string value)
 {
    if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
      {
        int enumIndex = ((IEnumerable<T>) typeof(T).GetEnumValues()).ToList().IndexOf(value); // this actually does not work and needs to be worked on 
             return  (Enum)Enum.ToObject(t, enumIndex);
       }
}
```

But assuming that I manage to make this method to correctly work, then the compiler does not seem to allow me to invoke it as I mean:

```
 string[] propertiesNames = ...;
  PropertyInfo propertyInfo = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(propertiesNames[i]));
  paramValue = CSVConvertParam<propertyInfo.PropertyType>(objectPropertiesValues[i]);
```

compiler does not accept  CSVConvertParam : 
"type or namespace propertyInfo cannot be found..."
I suppose that again, propertyInfo.PropertyType is a System.Type while  <> expects a concrete type.

Comment: Why not use `Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse`?

Comment: Agreed. The signature of this method looks the same as [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx), just with the parameters reversed.

Comment: because  Enum.TryParse would need me to know the concrete type.
Enum.TryParse<MyEnum >(value, out result) would work.
But I do not know what is the type at compile time.
I only have typeof(MyEnum ).
I do not know how to switch back from  my method parameter containing typeof(T) to the type T.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Enum.GetNames(type)`. This returns a `string[]` then you can find the index of your string in that array.

But, as others have said, you're probably just re-inventing `Enum.Parse(Type, string)`